# Probability theory question 2

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> A mathematics class is comprised of 10 economics students and 5 statistics students. All students in a class recently took a test.
>
> The probability that an economics student has a mark higher than 27 is 0.2. The probability that a statistics students has a mark higher than 27 is 0.3.
>
> If you picked a student from the class at random, what would be the probability that he or she would have a mark higher than 27?

NB- Please give your answer to THREE decimal places

Comment: Please see [these tips](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960/120540) for asking a good question. Right now, it looks like you've simply copied and pasted the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $10$ economics students and $5$ statistics students, so $$\dfrac{2+1.5}{15}=0.233...$$

Comment: @Ian oops, fixed it